# Will `_bookdown.yml` work in `blogdown` the same as `bookdown`?

Tags: r, r-markdown, hugo, bookdown, blogdown

I want to change the label of table and figures to another language (e.g., Chinese, and change `Figure 1.1` to `图1.1`). I found that, if I create a `_bookdown.yml` file with the following content:

```
language:
  label:
    fig: '图'
    tab: '表'
```

and put the file under the same directory of the posts, it works.

But if I have many `Section`s, or nested `Section`s, and I definitely want to add only one `_bookdown.yml` file in the `content/` folder only. For the subfolders would be included, the content of the `_bookdown.yml` should be:

```
language:
  label:
    fig: '图'
    tab: '表'
rmd_subdir: true
```

Unfornately, it does not work. Do my friends here know of any workaround solutions?

Comment: Here is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49440295/change-figure-and-table-captions-in-blogdown/49736062#49736062

Comment: @MikeyHarper Yes, thanks. It sortly solved my problem, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49440295/change-figure-and-table-captions-in-blogdown/49736062#49736062) and my own experiences, it can be affirmed that each section (directory) of post files should have a separate `_bookdown.yml` to make the configurations take effect.