# Change figure and table captions in blogdown

Tags: hugo, bookdown, blogdown

I'm tinkering with `blogdown` and would like to create figures and table with non-English caption headers. The following chunk

````
```{r label1, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="Fancy caption", fig.fullwidth=TRUE}
plot(1,1)
```
````

produces the plot and a caption that reads

> Figure 1: Fancy caption

I'd like to be able to change the label such that, say, "Figure" becomes "Plot". I thought I could fix it in the same way as for `bookdown`: In the `_bookdown.yml` file I could have

```
language:
  ui:
    chapter_name: "Chap "
    appendix_name: "App " 
  label:
    fig: 'Plot '
    tab: 'Fancy table '
```

but I'm not sure how to do something similar with a Hugo-based setup from `blogdown`. How can I add the above information to, say, the `config.toml` file or set it somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, store the `_bookdown.yml` file you described in the same folder as the blog post source `.Rmd` file, e.g. `content/post/_bookdown.yml` if your file is at `content/post/my_post.Rmd`.

Then, add `_bookdown.yml` to the list of `ignoreFiles` in your `config.toml` so that Hugo doesn't move `_bookdown.yml` to the public directory.

This works because `blogdown::html_page()` is based on `bookdown::html_document2()`, which will pick up the `_bookdown.yml` in the same directory of the source Rmd. I don't think it's possible to set this globally from your blogdown root dir, but if you store all your posts in `content/post` it's basically the same thing.

Comment: Wonderful. Thanks!

Comment: @grrrck are there other options for multilingual mode?